# Forbidden subgraph characterisation of interval graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, interval-graphs

A graph is an interval graph iff it is chordal and asteroidal triple free.
An interval graph is proper interval graph iff it is $K_{1,3}$ free.

However i googled intensely to find a minimal set of forbidden subgraphs for proper interval graphs,but in vain.

My question is : What are the minimal set of forbidden subgraphs for proper interval graphs ?
Any link to journal/paper is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ISGCI's page on proper interval graphs](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_298.html) (from our [FAQ](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science)) lists a few equivalent classes; one of them is the class of $(C_{n+4}$, $S_3$, claw, net)-free  graphs (see the same website for definitions).

Comment: These same forbidden graphs are also depicted in an illustration of the Wikipedia article on proper interval graphs, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_interval_graph

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following article: 
C.G. Lekkerkerker and J.C. Boland, Representations of a finite graph by a set of intervals on the line, Fund. Math. 45-64 (1962)

In this article, authors cite all the forbidden subgraphs to an interval graph thus a proper interval graph. The forbidden subgraphs are the following: 
 - a bipartite claw; 
 - n-net, n>=2; 
 - umbrella; 
 - n-tent, n>=3; 
 - Cn, n>=4.

Comment: Could you please expand the answer a little bit, summarizing how the article cited answers the question?

Comment: @chazisop, I've just edited my answer. I hope it'd help.